# Powershell Email body variable

Tags: email, powershell, variables

I am having an issue with capturing the results of a variable in acceptable/readable format which are sent through an email.

Following is the script I used,

```
$body = Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountExpired -SearchBase 'OU=Test1,OU=TEST,OU=Accounts,DC=home,DC=ac,DC=uk' | select SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, AccountExpirationDate

$emailto = 'test@home.ac.uk'
$emailfrom = 'AD-Accounts@home.ac.uk'
$emailserver = '127.0.0.1'

Send-MailMessage -To $emailto -From $emailfrom -Subject 'Expired Accounts' -Body $body -SmtpServer $emailserver
```

$body variable output is exactly what I want to see in the email body.

> SamAccountName DistinguishedName                                                    AccountExpirationDate
>   -------------- -----------------                                                    ---------------------
>   jumartin       CN=user one,OU=test1,OU=Test,OU=Accounts,DC=home,DC=ac,DC=uk 19/10/2016 00:00:00
>   ricohvalue     CN=user two,OU=test1,OU=TEST,OU=Accounts,DC=home,DC=ac,DC=uk        02/09/2016 00:00:00

However the email comes out blank if there are more than one expired user and if there is one expired user than it comes out in the following format:-

> @{SamAccountName=userone; DistinguishedName=CN=user one,OU=test1,OU=test,OU=Accounts,DC=home,DC=ac,DC=uk; AccountExpirationDate=10/19/2016 00:00:00}

All I am looking for is the SamAccountName, DistinguishedName and AccountExpirationDate in a nice line by line format in the body of email.

i dont know how i would capture what i see on the screen within a email. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i don't have Search-ADAccount to test with. Using the similar Get-QADUser from Quest gives me the following error when the CMDlet returns multiple users in an array:

```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'.
```

So best make sure that what you are putting in the body is a string.

```
Send-MailMessage -To $emailto -From $emailfrom -Subject 'Expired Accounts' -Body ($body | Out-String) -SmtpServer $emailserver
```

Or convert the table to proper HTML and use the BodyAsHtml parameter.

Comment: Adamar: that is great... its working as it should be. For my knowldge what was i doing wrong, why did i have to output $body to Out-String when it was already string captured in a variable... hopefully i can understand what i was missing. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Search-ADAccount returns an AD object. `| select` only turns the object into a custom object with the selected properties, no into a flat string. `| Out-String` however does. You can check for yourself: Compare `$body.GetType()` and `($body | Out-String).GetType()`